# GENE6 FTP Server Account (and alias) creation/deletion via C#

Tags: c#, ftp, server

Is it possible to programmatically create/delete accounts and their alias with C#?

Comment: Yes it should be possible to create new accounts. Check the COM Library example of their website:
http://www.g6ftpserver.com/manuals/devguide_en/